# Walkthrough for Converting Javascript Objects to Typescript Equivalents?

Tags: typescript

I'm tired enough of JavaScript's vagaries to be seriously considering porting a relatively large project to Typescript.  I've seen the tutorials and get the gist of Typescript, but I confess it would be really helpful if I saw some examples of "before" and "after" of going from JavaScript to Typescript.  In particular, converting from a few of the popular object definition patterns I've been aping (poorly) in JS.  For example, if I have a JS object declared like this:

```
var app = app || {};

app.SomeSingleton = function() {

var someProp;

var someFunction = function(e) {

};

var somePublicFunction = function(e) {

};

return {
    somePublicFunction: somePublicFunction
}

}();
```

Even just typing this out is helping me see I probably just recode property by property and method by method... but the weird (to me) inline class definition stuff in js still throws me.  So, same question as above, how would the following stub look when converted to TS?

```
var app = app || {};

app.MVVMThing = (function () {
    "use strict";

    //model
    var MVVMModel = (function () {
        LoggerInstanceDeclaredElsewhere.log("blah");

        var mvvmModel = {

            id: 'Id'

        };

        var datasource = "blah";

        return {
            model: mvvmDatasource
        };
    }());

    // view model
    var MVVMViewModel = (function () {

        var init = function () {

        };

        var show = function () {

        };

        return {
            init: init,
            show: show,           
        };
    }());

    return MVVMViewModel;
}());
```

And am I right that while there are many dialects of class definition and instantiation in JS there is really only one main way of doing this in TS?

Hoping someone who's a fan of TypeScript is willing to point me at the articles I couldn't find or provide their own response.

Thanks,
Dave Gerding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> many dialects of class definition and instantiation in JS there is really only one main way of doing this in TS

Mostly. But all valid JS is valid TS so you still have all that power.

## Module / Namespace pattern

What are you doing here :

```
var app = app || {};

app.SomeSingleton = function() {
}
```

Is using a module pattern. Similar to Namespaces in other languages. You are attaching the prefix `app` to SomeSingleton. In typescript:

```
module app{
    export function SomeSingleton(){} 
}
```

Which generates:

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    function SomeSingleton() {
    }
    app.SomeSingleton = SomeSingleton;
})(app || (app = {}));
```

Just more santized than your raw JS.

## Revealing Module pattern (for creating objects)

Your JS:

```
var SomeClass = function() {
    var someProp;
    var someFunction = function(e) {    };

    var somePublicFunction = function(e) {    };

    return {
        somePublicFunction: somePublicFunction
    }
};
```

Is perfectly valid TS, just more typesafe due to TypeScripts type inference:

[image]

Same for your singleton, its good TypeScript:

```
var SomeSingleton = function() {
    var someProp;
    var someFunction = function(e) {    };

    var somePublicFunction = function(e) {    };

    return {
        somePublicFunction: somePublicFunction
    }
} ();
```

To learn more just google : https://www.google.com.au/search?q=revealing%20module%20pattern